# Как можно сделать совместную работу двух пользователей на сайте?

Tags: javascript, ajax, websocket

**Здравствуйте!**
Делаю среду визуального программирования
Как можно сделать работу нескольких пользователей, чтобы когда один что-либо изменил, изменения сразу отображались у другого?

WebSocket, постоянные ajax-запросы к серверу, или есть какая-нибудь библиотека?

Comment: В базе данных(смотря какую используете), должна быть функция, которая позволяет реагировать на изменение данных

Comment: @likel0vsky всегда есть код, который формирует запрос к базе, в этот код вставить отправку данных по websocket - просто и надёжно